Low-level proof of identity related to Weierstrass P-function
A theorem which can be extracted from Theorem V.1.1 of Silverman's "advanced topics in the theory of elliptic curves" is the following. Here $\mathbb{Q}(u)$ denotes rational functions in a variable $u$ and $\mathbb{Q}(u)[[q]]$ denotes the formal power series ring in one variable $q$ over this field.
Make the following definitions (they're all elements of $\mathbb{Q}(u)[[q]]$, and $\sigma_k(n)$ is the sum of the $k$th powers of the positive divisors of $n$);
$$s_k=\sum_{n\geq1}\sigma_k(n)q^n;$$
$$a_4=-5s_3=-5q-45q^2-\cdots;$$
$$a_6=-\frac{5s_3+7s_5}{12}=-q-23q^2-\cdots;$$
$$X=\frac{u}{(1-u)^2}+\sum_{n\geq1}\left(\sum_{0<d\mid n}d(u^d+u^{-d}-2)\right)q^n=\frac{u}{(1-u)^2} + \frac{(1-u)^2}{u}q + \cdots;$$
$$Y=\frac{u^2}{(1-u)^3}+\sum_{n\geq1}\left(\sum_{0<d\mid n}\binom{d}{2}u^d-\binom{d+1}{2}u^{-d}+d\right)q^n=\frac{u^3}{(1-u)^3}+\frac{u-1}{u}q+\cdots.$$
Theorem. $$Y^2+XY=X^3+a_4X+a_6.$$
This is a purely algebraic statement. The proof in Silverman 2 is: first develop the theory of the Weierstrass $\mathcal{P}$-function, prove $\mathcal{P}'^2=4\mathcal{P}^3+g_4\mathcal{P}+g_6$ using complex analysis, and now work out the power series expansions of everything and all the powers of $\pi$ magically cancel and you get the result above. Theorem V.1.1 isn't quite stated like this but it's equivalent after a little elementary manipulation. Here is some pari-gp code which convinced me that I've not made a slip:
q
u
s3=sum(n=1,10,sigma(n,3)*q^n)+O(q^11)
s5=sum(n=1,10,sigma(n,5)*q^n)+O(q^11)
a4=-5*s3
a6=-(5*s3+7*s5)/12
X=u/(1-u)^2+sum(n=1,10,sumdiv(n,d,d*(u^d+u^(-d)-2))*q^n)+O(q^11)
Y=u^2/(1-u)^3+sum(n=1,10,sumdiv(n,d,d*(d-1)/2*u^d-d*(d+1)/2*u^(-d)+d)*q^n)+O(q^11)
Y^2+X*Y-X^3-a4*X-a6

and it duly prints out O(q^11) for the calculation.
I looked through the literature and I couldn't find anyone proving this directly, everyone seems to resort to the argument involving Weierstrass P. Is there a more low-level/elementary (note: I initially said "combinatorial" but see the comments) proof of this?
I'm interested in this identity because one can use it to analyse the $p$-adic points of an elliptic curve with multiplicative reduction, via the theory of the Tate curve, which has this identity as an input.

By 'combinatorial' are you thinking expanding out $X$ and $Y$ into formal power series in $u$ and $q$ and finding a way of equating terms? Do you have a combinatorial interpretation for either of them? (Very much looking forward to seeing if anyone has an answer to your question, incidentally; it's an excellent one!)

Combinatorialists sometimes reserve the term "purely combinatorial" for situations involving only positive integers (because then you can hope that the integers count some kind of combinatorial object). Is there a formulation of the identity that doesn't involve minus signs? Alternatively, what about a proof that doesn't use any analysis, and involves only manipulation of formal power series? Combinatorialists might not call such an argument "combinatorial" but maybe you'd be satisfied with it.

Some people use the word "combinatorial" for anything to do with (formal) power series. Other people call such things "analytic."

Sorry for the ambiguity -- I just mean "proof which involves goofing around with power series and no complex analysis"

I've removed the word "combinatorial" from the question because it has connotations which I didn't mean to imply.

I would even be interested in any argument avoiding the complex parametrisation, but high-brow algebraic geometry would be ok. Though Kevin might not want that.

A minor typo, it should be $Y=\frac{u^{\color{red}{2}}}{(1-u)^3}+\ldots$

It might be worth rewriting the double sums to instead be of the form $\sum_{d \ge 1} f(d) \frac{q^d}{1-q^d}$.

@i9Fn thanks -- fixed

We have the identity $(\partial X/\partial u)/(2Y+X) = 1/u$, which expresses the fact that the invariant differential is $du/u$ (since $u=e^{2\pi iz}$). It seems easy to prove.

Here are two other approaches to the formula, one of which may satisfy you, depending on your tastes:

Roquette's Analytic Theory of Elliptic Functions over Local Fields includes a self-contained discussion of this formula in Section 3 on pages 23 to 29. Roquette's approach, though, is (non-Archimedean) analytic and also uses a bit of the theory of genus-1 function fields--not really low-level.

In the paper where he introduces the tau function, "On certain arithmetical functions," Ramanujan sketches a direct proof of something related to $(\wp')^2 = 4\wp^3 + a_4\wp + a_6$, namely $\wp'' = 6\wp^2 + \frac{a_4}{2}$ (Equation (21) in that paper). One can find some further details of the computations in Chapter 4 ("Eisenstein Series") of Berndt's Number Theory in the Spirit of Ramanujan, but Berndt leaves part of the work as an exercise for his readers. A more comprehensive treatment, generalizing Ramanujan's approach, is in the first chapter of Development of Elliptic Functions According to Ramanujan by Venkatachaliengar and Cooper. The authors reach $(\wp')^2 = 4\wp^3 + a_4\wp + a_6$ at the bottom of page 11. Perhaps by reducing the generality of Venkatachaliengar and Cooper's intermediate formulas, one could produce a minimal low-level proof that fills in the details of Ramanujan's sketch.


